# Pyqt multiple signlas, one slot

Tags: pyqt, signals-slots

I have 16 `QDoubleSpinBoxes` and I want to know when the user change a data in one of that. 
Note that I don't care which one has been changed I only need to know that one of them has changed.

How can I do it without writing 16 different `valueChanged()` signals/slot? Is it possible to connect a "generic" `valueChanged()` to a slot?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a list from your QSpinBox's, and use a for loop for that:

```
for box in mySpinBoxes:
    box.valueChanged.connect(self.myFunction)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can connect as many signals as you want to the same slot. (But indeed you will need to connect the 16 signals individually.)

Answer (score 0):

You can connect all signals to the same slot, and then you can get the sender with the `QObject.sender` method. Or you better look at the [`QSignalMapper`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qsignalmapper.html) class.